# Common Practice when popup a alert dialog in my activity

Tags: android

In my activity, I have an instance variable of AlertDialog aDialog;
under some condition, my activity will pop up a dialog.

My question is if I create aDialog, do I need to dismiss() in my onDestory() or onPause() of my activity?

Comment: it will give you some unharmful error if you don't dismiss, you can check that in the log, when you try to go to another activity without dismissing dialog.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, no. If you've called `aDialog.show()` and it's still showing while the activity is ending or pausing, it may be good to call `dismiss()`. I don't remember too clearly, but I have had experiences where forgetting to dismiss/close a dialog when switching activities caused a slight undesired, but not problematic, flickering of the dialog on the next activity as it tries to force close the dialog. Hope this answers your question!